# Desviación estándar de la diferencia entre valores pre y post

Tags: estadística

Estoy llevando a cabo un meta-análisis y algunos de los artículos sólo proporcionan la media y la desviación típica pre-intervención y post-intervención. Necesito calcular la media y la desviación estándar de la diferencia entre pre-intervención y post-intervención de cada grupo.
Adjunto una imagen para ayudar a la explicación.[image: tabla de resultados] Resumiendo: partiendo de los datos de la primera y segunda columna ¿podría calcular los datos de la tercera columna? Quisiera saber si existe alguna vía en STATA (o en cualquier otro software) para realizar el cálculo que necesito.
Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.
Iker

Comment: No termino de comprender la pregunta (y parece basada en opiniones).. vos queres saber si de dos medias se puede calcular otra media?? porque ahi, la terecer columna es una recta directa...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La diferencia entre las medias (mean) sí es una resta, pero lo que quisiera saber es si es posible calcular el valor de SD de la tercera columna si dispongo sólo de los datos de las dos primeras columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguno le sirve, ya he encontrado la solución. Podéis leerla aquí:
https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/16_1_3_2_imputing_standard_deviations_for_changes_from_baseline.htm